# How to set the date of bootstrap-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I've set up [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EmwFE/25/) JSFiddle showing my problem.

```
$('#dp3').datepicker();
var date = new Date('2009-05-05');
$('#dp3').datepicker('setDate', date);
```

It seems like a rather simple thing to do, and I feel I may be overlooking something, but this should work, shouldn't it? I'm simply trying to set the date of the calendar to a specific day.

I know there are methods to use to set the start date in the HTML mark-up, but this is not what I need to do. This needs to be done in JavaScript.

There's documentation [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) that I looked over, but the "setDate" option doesn't seem to do as it says it does.

Thanks.

Comment: The js file in your fiddle is different than the one on the page in github. It would seem that the one on the fiddle is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#dp3').datepicker('setValue', date);` or `$('#dp3').datepicker('update', date);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dp3').datepicker();
    var date = new Date('2009-05-05');
    $('#dp3').datepicker('setDate', date);
});
```

See you **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EmwFE/32/)**